# C++ Child class can't access other child class vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

At a loss here hope someone can help..

I have the following class structure.

A base class Room with two child classes `Kitchen`, and `livingRoom`.

I have a vector in my base class

```
Room::Room()
{
    up = nullptr;
    down = nullptr;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;

    pocket = new vector<string>; 

}
```

Defined as:

```
void Room::addPocket(string item)
{
    char emptyPocket;

    if (pocket->size()==1)
    {
        emptyPocket = 'N';
    }

    if(pocket->size()<1)
        {
            pocket->push_back(item);
            cout << "Item added to pocket" << endl;
        }
    else
        {
        cout <<"Your pocket is full" << endl;
        cout <<"Would you like to empty your pocket? 'Y' or 'N'" << endl;
        cin >> emptyPocket;
        if(emptyPocket == 'Y' || emptyPocket == 'y')
        {
            pocket->clear();
            cout <<"You have emptied your pocket." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And my program function as follows. I have a another class `Game`, where the following happens. I go into the `child` class `Kitchen` and add to the vector. Go back into `Game` class. I move into the `livingRoom` class and when I access the vector, is empty? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Why on earth: `pocket = new vector<string>; `??

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Expanding on a comment above, you almost never want to dynamically allocate a `std::vector`. A dynamically allocated vector puts part of the memory management onus back on the programmer and defeats about half of the point of using `vector` in the first place.

Comment: "pocket = new vector<string>;" - *why*? Why not just a plain member `vector`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base class data is not shared between different instances of child classes. Each child class is, and effectively contains, a distinct instance of the base class.

So `Kitchen` has a `pocket` and `livingRoom` has another `pocket`. What is added to `Kitchen`'s `pocket` is not added to `LivingRoom`'s pocket.

Instead, you should look into making another class to represent the entity that is moving between the rooms and have this entity class contain `pocket`. No matter what room an entity is in, it always has the same `pocket`.

Also shy away from dynamically allocating `std::vector`s. They were designed to take away all of the responsibilities of managing dynamic allocations, so dynamically allocating a `vector` merely puts some of the those management responsibilities back into play for no benefit.